# Book about a 'blue hour'

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book or book series that I read a long time ago. I don't remember many details, but I do know it's about a blue hour. It's an hour after midnight where time stands still and it is only available for the 'gifted'. Most people don't notice it but the gifted are able to walk around freely while everyone is frozen.

I'm not entirely sure if there are also monsters involved, who can also walk around in that hour.

Comment: How much is "long time ago"?  How old were you?  Was the book old or new at the time?  Can you bring to mind any visualisation of the cover of the book?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [The Secret Hour](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24766.The_Secret_Hour)

The Secret Hour is a science-fiction fantasy novel written by Scott Westerfeld.  It was published in 2004.

It is the first of a trilogy, the two sequels being: Touching Darkness (2005), and Blue Noon (2006).

> Strange things happen at midnight in the town of Bixby, Oklahoma. **Time freezes. Nobody moves except dark creatures that haunt the shadows and the few people who are free to move at midnight, Midnighters.**
>
> Their different powers are strongest at midnight: Seer, Mindcaster, Acrobat, Polymath.
>
> All changes when Jessica Day comes to Bixby High with a hidden power.

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Hour)

Comment: Thank you! Reading the synopsis I think it's the same book!